# MultiValueDictKeyError "iSortingCols"

Tags: django, datatables

I'm working on adding an ajax-loaded table to a django app, and I'm seeing a MultiValueDictKeyError when I use inspect element to see why the table isn't loading.

When I google MultiValueDictKeyError all of the results seem to be of the form "Key X not found in Y", but all I get is "iSortingCols". Furthermore, the traceback provided doesn't involve any of my files, just ones from various python libraries.

Traceback:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eztables/views.py in get
        return self.process_dt_response(request.GET) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eztables/views.py in process_dt_response
        self.form = DatatablesForm(data) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eztables/forms.py in __init__
        for idx in xrange(int(self.data['iSortingCols'])): ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__
            raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key)) ...
▶ Local vars
```

GET:

```
mDataProp_8 
u'name'
mDataProp_9 
u'name'
mDataProp_4 
u'name'
mDataProp_5 
u'name'
mDataProp_6 
u'name'
mDataProp_7 
u'name'
mDataProp_0 
u'name'
sEcho   
u'1'
iDisplayStart   
u'0'
mDataProp_1 
u'name'
mDataProp_10    
u'name'
mDataProp_2 
u'name'
sColumns    
u''
iColumns    
u'11'
mDataProp_3 
u'name'
_   
u'1389632300296'
iDisplayLength  
u'-1'
```

I'm not entirely surprised that I'm getting errors, as I'm not super familiar with the whole datatable setup, but I'm not sure where this one is coming from.

Does anyone know what might possibly be causing this error?

Comment: Please do post the traceback, even if it doesn't involve any of your files

Comment: @sk1p Added the traceback

Comment: It looks like you're using the DataTables framework? If so you need to make sure you're reading the GET (or POST) parameters properly. Post a snippet of the code in question, that would help more.

Comment: @themanatuf Yeah, I am. What section would be helpful to show? The JS in question?

Comment: @StephenTG it would be good to see the Python/Django function being called when you make that AJAX request.

Comment: Posting the actual GET data (for example from the network tab of your browser's development tools) of your ajax request would also help

Comment: Added the GET data. The reason 'name' is repeated so much is that the table will have 11 columns, but I'm just getting it set up with a simple field before I worry about some of the ones that will take a bit more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-eztables [expects a parameter `iSortingCols`](https://github.com/noirbizarre/django-eztables/blob/master/eztables/forms.py#L51), which is the number of columns to sort on. If you are not sorting on any, try to submit a `0` from your JS code.

Comment: Do you mean put something like `"iSortingCols": 0,` in the list of options for the datatable object I'm creating in the JS?

Comment: I mean: whatever generates the ajax request needs to send `"iSortingCols": 0` to make the `DatatablesForm` work. The [datatables documentation](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) says that it will send this value, but maybe it only does if any sort columns are defined?

Comment: Setting bSort back to true is giving me a different error now, so that makes it seem like that's what was causing this one

Comment: If setting `bSort` to false causes this error, you might have found a bug in eztables. Consider [submitting it to the appropriate issue tracker](https://github.com/noirbizarre/django-eztables/issues)

Comment: Submitted the bug. I guess I'll leave the table as sortable for now, not that it's actually useful to do so. Thanks for the help tracking this down.